# Why Google Admob ads are not getting displayed (java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AdsAttrs)?

Tags: android, admob

I had the ads running before but i don't understand why it's not running now.

I get the following error in the `xml`

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AdsAttrs
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzj.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Here is my `xml` code

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adslayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the activity i'm calling it as

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("--------
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adslayout.addView(mAdView);
```

Comment: Did you add `<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />` into `application` tag of your Manifest file?

Comment: no i did not but without the following ads were getting displayed before

Comment: Did you migrate to playservices recently..if yes then try to clean and rebuild..

Comment: well for some reason it's working now but sometime it doesn't work at all why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. if you use firebase, check your module app. Fistly check compile version in dependencies. For example,  ***'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'***. You will get the above error but the problem will be resolved as follows. ***compile 
'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1' com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1***

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that having same problem, check  your gradle module app if have no incompatibility between versions of  compiles from  google. I solved my problem  just right now by removing a compile of app indexing that was causing imcompatibility with a compile from firebase NOTE: That compile was not usefull for me, that's why I deleted it, otherwise i  just would try to change compiles to a same version, hope this help. (sorry about the english im Brazilian without any english course)